# What means '2e4' in code

Tags: javascript, raphael

This example http://raphaeljs.com/gear.html
has following code:

```
function run() {
                e.animate({along: 1}, 2e4, function () {
                    e.attr({along: 0});
                    setTimeout(run);
                });
            }
```

What means "2e4" in this example and how it works?

Comment: @Baszz: unless prefixed with `0x`, it's not hexadecimal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

it means 2*10^4
and try it in your console `2e4` the output will be `20000`

the `e` is the [scientific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) notation

the code is equivilant to

```
...
e.animate({along: 1}, 20000, function () { ....
```

Answer (score 7):

`2e4` is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) for `2 * 10^4`, and therefore has the same value as 20000.